# Reducing a quadratic algorithm to linear time

Tags: algorithm, runtime, pseudocode

I am trying to write an algorithm that runs in O(n) time. Essentially, it takes an integer n and multiplies a sum by a coefficient. However, my first attempt at writing this algorithm runs in O(n^2) time. (See below.) Is there any way I can reduce the runtime?

```
for i = 1 to n
    num1 = i/n
    num2 = 0
    for j = i to n-1
        num2 = num2 + 1/j
    result[i] = num1 * num2
```

Comment: Count `i` down. Update `num2` incrementally.

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach is running in quadratic time because, for each element in the sequence `1..n` you are iterating over the sequence again.  You can remove the extra work by realizing that you only really need to compute the `num2` summation *once*.  After this, it can be reused.

```
num2 = 0
for j = 1 to n-1
    num2 = num2 + 1/j

for i = 1 to n
    num1 = i/n
    if (i > 1)
        num2 = num2 - 1/(i-1)   // reuse the summation by subtracting
    result[i] = num1 * num2     // off the portion you don't want for this value of i
```

Comment: I downvoted this solution because due to truncation error the de-summation will not work very precisely. The suggestion by @DavidEisenstat is better.

Comment: @Yves I disagree with you.  Adding up the summation term-by-term is in principle no different than starting off with the sum and subtracting term-by-term.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic isn't exact. There is rounding. The error grows linearly with the number of terms.

Comment: The number of FLOPS should be the same whether we do a bottom-up approach (Eisenstat) or top down.  If this be incorrect, please explain why the order of operations will affect the precision.

Comment: FLOPS have nothing to do here (and by the way your solution has a double cost). In FP, `(a+b)-b != a+(b-b)`, this is a well-known fact.